# Mongodb change boolean to false after some time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The following is the basic structure of my schema : 
[image]

Whenever I update the value of one of the "powerups"(first 4 items), I set the powerupTimer to the time one of these fields was changed (only 1 powerup can be active at a time). I want the all the values to be false after 1 hour, I am not able to figure out how I can reset them 1 hour after the time was recorded.

I am thinking of going with this approach but am not too sure about its impact on performance and limitations of the m0 free cluster:

I will set the field "powerupTimer" to be 60, and decrease it by 1 every minute (making a cron job) and when it is equal to zero, I will set the top four fields to be false.

Obviously, there must be a better way to implement a timer function like this in mongodb, please help me in implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your idea of a cron job that executes every minute.

But you can just perform an `update` request witch set the fields to `false` when `powerupTimer` is lower than the current hour minus one hour.

Comment: But how will I check if the poweruptimer is lower than the current hour minus one hour? I will still have to execute a cron job every minute right (considering the timer was started between two hours, I cant execute a cron job every hour)?

Comment: Yes but by doing that, it will only execute one request each minute, witch is not too mutch. Or maybe If having some delay doesn't bother you, on settings your fields too false. You maybe can launch the cron every 10 minutes or 2 minutes, if you want to reduce the number of mongo request

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and it does work, I just hope the number of mongo requests dont harm the outcome! accepting your answer :)

Comment: It depends on the size of your data and on your server. But at my company, we have several crons that run each minute doing a heavier computation that just a request. So don't worry it should work well